# WebClient vs. RestTemplate SSL Connection

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm calling the same API endpoint once with `WebClient`, and once with `RestTemplate`.  The `RestTemplate` call succeeds, the `WebClient` call fails due to `handshake_failure`.

Here's the configuration for my `WebClient` bean.

```java
@Bean
WebClient webClient(String baseUrl,
                    @Value("classpath:bundle.pem") Resource pemBundleResource) throws Exception {
    final SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
        .forClient()
        .trustManager(pemBundleResource.getInputStream())
        .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
        .create()
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));

    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build();
}
```

I've also tried an `InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE` to ignore SSL altogether, but that request fails as well with the same error which tells me the configuration might not be getting used.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the stack trace:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:91)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1494)
    at com.example.APITestsIT.callApi(APITestsIT.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1330)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1272)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace and message of the failure

Comment: I added the stacktrace from the JUnit, note, I've added all the `.protocols("SSLv3","TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2")` to my `SslContext`

Comment: target endpoint is tls 1.2

Comment: @dardo: Have you ever resolved your problem?

Answer (score 4):

This one might work in your case,

```
# The ciphers which are needed
val allowedCiphers = listOf("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384")

@Bean
fun webClient(): WebClient {
    val sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .protocols("SSLv3","TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2")
            .ciphers(allowedCiphers)
            .build();

    val httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .secure { it.sslContext(sslContext) }

    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works with spring-boot 2.5.2 and httpclient5

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.*;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.*;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.*;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.*;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.nio.*;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.*;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.config.*;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.config.Lookup;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.nio.ssl.*;
import org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.*;
import org.apache.hc.core5.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.*;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.*;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

@Value("${webclient.connection-timeout-millis:60000}")
protected long connectionTimeout;

@Value("${webclient.response-timeout-millis:300000}")
protected long responseTimeout;

@Value("${webclient.request-timeout-millis:300000}")
protected long requestTimeout;

@Bean
public WebClient webClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(requestTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setResponseTimeout(responseTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setHardCancellationEnabled(true)
            .setConnectionKeepAlive(TimeValue.ofHours(1))
            .build();

    final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy())
            .build();

    final Lookup<TlsStrategy> tlsStrategyLookup = RegistryBuilder.<TlsStrategy>create()
            .register("https", new DefaultClientTlsStrategy(sslcontext))
            .build();

    final AsyncClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager(tlsStrategyLookup);

    CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients
            .custom()
            .useSystemProperties()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .build();

    // init spring-boot wrapper for httpclient5
    WebClient wc = WebClient
            .builder()
            .clientConnector(new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(client))
            .build();


    return wc;
}
}
```